# How could I use a dynamic espilon in a DBSCAN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Today I'm working on a dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data. I would like to segment my dataset by beds, baths, neighborhood and use a DBSCAN to get a clustering by price in each segment. The problem is because each segment is different, I don't want to use the same epsilon for all my dataset but for each segment the best epsilon, do you know an efficient way to do it ?

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import sklearn.utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sklearn.utils.check_random_state(1000)
Clus_dataSet = pdf[['beds','baths','neighborhood','price']]
Clus_dataSet = np.nan_to_num(Clus_dataSet)
Clus_dataSet = StandardScaler().fit_transform(Clus_dataSet)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=6).fit(Clus_dataSet)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
pdf["Clus_Db"]=labels

realClusterNum=len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
clusterNum = len(set(labels))
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you planning to apply DBscan on each segment separately with different eps? Or at the same time?

Comment: Hi, on each segment separately

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic for the setting of Epsilon and MinPts parameters has been proposed [in the original DBSCAN paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf)

Once the MinPts value is set (e.g. 2 ∗ Number of features) the partitioning result strongly depends on Epsilon. The heuristic suggests to infer epsilon through a visual analysis of the *k-dist* plot.

A toy example of the procedure with two gaussian distributions is reported in the following.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_biclusters
data,lab,_ = make_biclusters((200,2), 2, noise=0.1, minval=0, maxval=1)
minpts = 4
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=minpts, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(data) 
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(data)
k_dist = [x[-1] for x in distances]
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize = (10,5))
ax[0].set_title('k-dist plot for k = minpts = 4') 
ax[0].plot(sorted(k_dist))
ax[0].set_xlabel('object index after sorting by k-distance')
ax[0].set_ylabel('k-distance')
ax[1].set_title('original data')
ax[1].scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],c = lab[0])
```

In the resulting k-dist plot, the "elbow" theoretically divides noise objects from cluster objects and indeed gives an indication on a plausible range of values for Epsilon (tailored on the dataset in combination with the selected value of MinPts). In this toy example, I would say between 0.05 and 0.075.

[image: k-dist]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I'm really looking for is few differents epsilon each time on each different segment to understand the market. (It will be a kind of dbscan for each segment)